# EF 7 Include a collection with where clause and then a collection one level down

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to query a collection and child collection using EF 7. Here's the code:

```
var customerID = 86795;
var query = await _context.Contacts
            .Where(g => g.CustomerID == customerID )
            .Include(g => g.Address.Where(p => p.AddressTypeID == 1))
            .ThenInclude(p=> p.City)
            .ToListAsync();


> Error CS1061  'IEnumerable<Address>' does not contain a definition for
> 'City' and no extension method 'City' accepting a first argument of
> type 'IEnumerable<Address>' could be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)  Contacts.DNX 4.5.1, Contacts.DNX
> Core 5.0
```

It works fine when I just use

```
var customerID = 86795;
var query = await _context.Contacts
            .Where(g => g.CustomerID == customerID )
            .Include(g => g.Address)
            .ThenInclude(p=> p.City)
            .ToListAsync();
```

But this will load all the addresses for the customer where I only want the recent address for which the AddressTypeID is 1.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [anonymous projection](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/querying-entity-graph-in-entity-framework.aspx), that will fetch translate your query into SQL.

```
var customerID = 86795;
var query = await _context.Contacts
                  .Where(g => g.CustomerID == customerID)
                  .Select(cntct=> new
                  {
                     contact = cntct,
                     address = cntct.Address.Where(p => p.AddressTypeID == 1),
                     city    = cntct.Address.Where(p => p.AddressTypeID == 1)
                                            .Select(h=>h.City),
                  }.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't filter in Include. In any version of entity framework.

If you need to load a subset of the collection then you need to Join instead of using navigation property and filter whenever you need using Where clause

Like this (simplified, extra steps for readability):

```
var filteredAddresses = Addresses.Where(x=>x.AddressTypeId==1);

var customersWithAddress = Customers.Join(filteredAddresses, x=>x.Id,x=>x.CustomerId,(c,a)=> new {
    Customer=c,
    Address=a
});
```

Or if you need a single customer, assuming you have Customer navigation property in Address:

```
var addressWithCustomer = Addresses
    .Where(x=>x.AddressTypeId==1 && x.CustomerId == customerId)
    .Include(x=>x.Customer)
    .Include(x=>x.City)
    .Single();
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. But I would  prefer an answer with suggession on how to do this in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times, it is better to approach queries which involve conditional nested entities, to start with the nested entity, apply the conditions to this nested fellow and then project out the parent entity, since it is always easier to reach to the parent entities from the nested enumerable ones. (many to one)

in our case, we can apply the filter out on the Address entity and then group it on the Contact entity.

```
var customerID = 86795;
var query = await _context.Addresses
            .Where(a => a.Contact.CustomerID == customerID 
                        && a.Contact.RegistrationDate.Year == 2016 
                        && a.AddressTypeID == 1)
            .Include(a => a.Contact)
            .Include(a => a.City)
            .GroupBy(a => a.Contact)
            .Take(20)  // by the way, you should apply some orderby for a predicatble Take
            .ToListAsync();
```

and if you absolutely want a list of Contacts as the output of the above query, you can do this.

```
var contacts = query.Select(g => 
{
 g.Key.Addresses = g.ToList();
 return g.Key;
}).ToList();

// now you can work off the Contacts list, which has only specific addresses
```

This will basically give you a grouped list of all Contacts with CustomerID, and with those address types and registration years only. The important thing here is to iterate through the group to get the addresses, and not use the grouping.Key.Addresses navigation. (grouping.Key will be the Contact entity)

Also, I don't know if CustomerID is a primary key on the Contact entity, but if it is, it looks like you would just need a list of matching addresses for one Contact. In that case, the query would be:

```
var query = await _context.Addresses
            .Where(a => a.Contact.CustomerID == customerID && a.AddressTypeID == 1)
            .Include(a => a.Contact)
            .Include(a => a.City)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks fo the answer Raja but I can't start with addressess cuase I need to query for 10 most recent/old customers and want to get their contacts with addressess including city details plus phone numbers (which is in another table)

Comment: So the query would eventually look like
 
`var query = await _context.Contacts
            .Where(g => g.CustomerID == customerID )
   .Where(g => g.RegistrationDate.Year == 2016)
            .Include(g => g.Address.Where(p => p.AddressTypeID == 1))
            .ThenInclude(p=> p.City)
   .Include(g => g.Phone)
            .Take(20).ToListAsync();`

Comment: @MobarukH there is not much difference between what you need and my groupby query. you can do a Take(20) on the output of my query to get the results you need. Take(20) doesn't differentiate our results. The only difference is that if you use the groupby, you need to access the addresses from the groupedItem values, not contact.Addresses. to fix that, i have edited the answer and included an additional line, which populates the filtered addresses as navigation properties on Contact entity, so that you now work with just the Contact entity.

Answer (score 0):

Include The Collection for Eager Load then use Any instead of Where ... to Select specific items in the child of the wanted entity.

```
var customerID = 86795;
var query = await _context.Contacts
        .Where(g => g.CustomerID == customerID )
        .Include(g => g.Address.Any(p => p.AddressTypeID == 1))
        .ThenInclude(p=> p.City)
        .ToListAsync();
```